FPGA direct coaxial output is not working
I am using a Zynq device and trying to create a coaxial output port. To achieve this, I first connected the output of the I/O port to an LED and verified that it works correctly by inputting it into an AMP through an SPDIF optical output.
However, when I connected the output of the SPDIF I/O port directly to the coaxial output port, the AMP could not recognize the output.
What might be wrong with this circuit?

SPDIF out I/O:  2----------------------------   SPDIF in

                1----------------------------   GND
                     |
                     -
                ground


What is the spdif input specification? Compare that with the input spec for the optical driver.

That's no way to make a proper coaxial S/PDIF interface, by connecting the coax cable directly to a digital output (or input) pin. It may even damage something (the FPGA or the next device). Coaxial S/PDIF is not a logic level interface.
The FPGA digital pin cannot drive the load presented by the cable or the input directly.
The coaxial S/PDIF interface has only 0.5Vpp swing (terminated) and it is a 75 ohm system, so the input is a 75 ohm impedance, the cable should have 75 ohm characteristic impedance, and thust the FPGA should have a 75 ohm output impedance for driving the cable.
There must also be no DC voltage present so you need to have a DC blocking capacitor. Well made S/PDIF interfaces use transformer isolation instead of just AC coupling with capacitor.
The least you can do is to implement DC blocing and voltage divider for setting the output voltage and impedance correctly, but then again you need to be sure that the FPGA pin can drive the cable and load with enough current, or if you should need buffering.
